# Nativescript app size is growing each time when a new screen is added

Tags: nativescript

I have `10 xml files`, and `23 js files`, and `1 css file`

`4 font styles`, `25 10kb images`. Thats all

my `app` folder size is `2.77 mb`

these are the dependencies

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.higherstudy",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "^1.1.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^6.1.1",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "94f487c5279f7abc2cc61cb48e357d1756865a40",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

when i build the app on `Sidekick` the size of apk file is `43,873kb` which is `43mb`

each time when i add xml js file the size was growing with a range of `5 to 8 mb` in size.

`is it time to stop using nativescript` who will download my simple app with big size.

the problem video link https://youtu.be/FtcbagvDqR8

Comment: Can you share a sample repo where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: its simple, Create `tns create test_app` of pure javacript version and simply build android app in `side kick` the size was `28 mb` in my case. then if u add above plugin `size will grow in mb's`

Comment: @Manoj please not that before this webpack the app size was around `14 Mb`. So, webpack is a very bad update for nativescript. So, i need a way to use nativescript without webpack as it increases the size of app.

Comment: I may agree that {N} could allow without webpack, if not for size reason still others. But I'm not sure if webpack could just be the reason for your app size, actually speaking webpack helps with reducing bundle size. I have apps with 30+ screens, images etc., and the size stays at 24mb still.

Comment: @Manoj i think you need to create a fresh app. my old apps which i migrated to ns6 is still 30+ mb only. and those apps are complete ready to release on playstore. but Now if you create an app on windows the size was big. I mean the basic hello world app size is 28 mb.

Comment: @Manoj look at this 50 second video https://youtu.be/FtcbagvDqR8